# How to get access to Airbnb API? or Airbnb correct token?

Tags: .net-core, token

There are a few old, unofficial Airbnb APIs, and Airbnb is not giving access to new partners.

If I get an Airbnb token to approve Airlock, I am still not able to access reservations.

Maybe anyone has alternative solution?

https://api.nobeds.com

```
public string GetAirbnbAPIToken(string email, string password)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var uri = new Uri("https://www.airbnb.com/api/v2/logins");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-airbnb-api-key", "your api key");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-airbnb-device-id", "111111111111111");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", "Airbnb/19.18 AppVersion/19.18 iPhone/12.2 Type/Phone");

        var credentials = new
        {
            email = email,
            password = password,
            type = "email"
        };

        var response = client.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(credentials), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result.Content;
        string responce = response.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        Debug.WriteLine("Airbnb responce: " + responce);

        //Open Airlock
        try
        {
            //https://www.airbnb.com/airlock?al_id=AIRLOCK_ID
            dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responce);
            string airlock = Convert.ToString(json.client_error_info.airlock.airlockId);
            return "https://www.airbnb.com/airlock?al_id=" + airlock;
        }
        catch
        {

        }

        //Parse reservations
        try
        {
            dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responce);
            string token = Convert.ToString(json.login.id);
            return Reservations(token).ToString();
        }
        catch
        {
            return "Airbnb token error: " + responce;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have documentation to the Nobeds API?